# Computing intermediate results only once in scikit-learn GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have an estimator like this:

```
    from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
    import numpy as np

    class customEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, estimator_var):
            self.estimator_var = estimator_var
        def transform(self, X):
            self.tmpVar = np.random.randn(estimator_var, estimator_var)
            return np.hstack((self.tmpVar, X)) # this is just an example
        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self
        def get_params(self, deep=False):
            return {'estimator_var': self.estimator_var, 'tmpVar': tmpVar}
```

I then create a pipeline with the estimator in it (and others) and feed it into GridSearchCV for k-fold cross validation. k-fold cross validation goes something like this:

```
for all possible params combination:
   for every fold split
     compute score(mini_train, mini_test)
   compute average score
pick best combination
```

The issue is that, for a given combination of parameters, I would like to compute `self.tmpVar` (which may be slow to compute) only once, and use it for all fold splittings that share the same combination of parameters.

Would that be possible in scikit-learn, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Simply store this variable as a **static attribute** of your class, or in any other global name scope.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class customEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    tmpVar = None

    def __init__(self, estimator_var):
        self.estimator_var = estimator_var
    def transform(self, X):
        if customEstimator.tmpVar is None:
            customEstimator.tmpVar = np.random.randn(estimator_var, estimator_var)
        return np.hstack((customEstimator.tmpVar, X)) # this is just an example
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'estimator_var': self.estimator_var}
```

Of course here the problem is if you reuse your estimator many times, with different data, sometimes you **do** want to reset. Then you can simply have a name for each estimator, and store these tmpVars in a map (dictionary) with these names as keys. You can even make names to be generated automatically, by something among the lines of:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class customEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    tmpVars = {}
    estimators = 0

    def __init__(self, estimator_var, name=None):
        if name is None:
            customEstimator.estimators = customEstimator.estimators + 1
            name = 'Estimator %d' % customEstimator.estimators
        self.name = name
        self.estimator_var = estimator_var
    def transform(self, X):
        if self.name not in customEstimator.tmpVar:
            customEstimator.tmpVar[self.name] = np.random.randn(estimator_var, estimator_var)
        return np.hstack((customEstimator.tmpVar[self.name], X)) # this is just an example
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        return {'estimator_var': self.estimator_var, 'name': self.name}
```

This way if you create a new instance of customEstimator, it will get a new name, but if it is cloned by scikit-learn, they will share the same name (and consequently - data).

Comment: thank you very much! one question: since the __init__ method is invoked every time, I supposed they are different physical objects. But I guess scikit learn, when working with the same set of parameters in GridSearchCV, will use the same name variable when calling __init__. Would that be correct?

Comment: Each instance of customEstimator is a different object, but "tmpVars" in my example are **static**, meaning that they are shared across all instances. This is not scikit-learn's feature, this is how static attributes work in general, in every programming language. And yes, the idea is to make sure that if you use scikit-learn's cloning - you will get the same name, and will be able to retrieve the same part of memory.